# Converting Text Field to Numeric in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: field-calculator, arcgis-pro, python-parser, null

I'm trying to convert text to numeric, but am unable to in ArcGIS Pro.

Is there a Python function?

I tried `int(!FieldName!)` but I think NULL values are messing it up?

Comment: Certainly, `None` input will fail in a cast. You need to conditionally process the calculation.

Comment: I am assuming that you are using the Calculate Field tool and have tagged your question accordingly but it would be better if you also make that clear in your question body

Comment: is this helpful? https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000002287 about 2/3 down is for Pro, with note on NULL

Comment: The example  support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000002287  for Pro just mentions that it's going to fail on blanks, no solution on how to get around that problem for Pro

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace the Null values with 0s using the field calculator. In python, None (NULL) has a data type of NoneType, which is not the same as a string. This has been confirmed by other threads: https://community.esri.com/thread/37019

And I just confirmed that mattwatt's field calculation in python successfully converts Nulls to 0s. See his comment below.

Comment: e.g. `int(!FieldName!) if !FieldName! else 0`